# Why does my program work in Safari, Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox, but not in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

I have made 4 questions in a html document and the function is made in jquery.
The program works in Safari, Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox, but not in Internet Explorer..
Has anyone an idea how to make my program also work in internet explorer?

```
  <html>    
    <head>
        <title>Inboedelwaardemeter</title>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

               function checkTotal() {
                   var a =  document.querySelectorAll('input:checked'); 
                   var total = 0;
                   for(var x=0; x < a.length;x++){
                      total += parseFloat( a[x].value );
                   }
                  alert('Uw puntenaantal is '+ total+'. Kunt u dit aantal en uw postcode, huisnummer en eventuele toevoeging terugsturen naar warnersteinfort@gmail.com');
                }
        </script>
    </head> 
    <body>
    <center><h1>Inboedelwaardemeter</h1></center>
        <b> Leeftijd hoofdkostwinner:</b>
        <form name="mijnForm1">
        <br>
            <input type="radio" id="getal1" name="leeftijd"
                value="22" checked> 35 jaar en jonger
              <br>    
            <input type="radio" id="getal2" name="leeftijd"
                value="29"> 36 t/m 50 jaar
              <br>
            <input type="radio" id="getal3" name="leeftijd"
                value="38"> 51 jaar en ouder
              <br>
            <br>
        <b> Samenstelling huishouden:</b>
        <br>
        <form name="mijnForm2">
            <input type="radio" id="getal4" name="huishouden"
                value="0" checked> Alleenstaande
              <br>    
            <input type="radio" id="getal5" name="huishouden"
                value="10"> Echtpaar / Samenwonende
              <br>
              <br>  
        <b> Netto maandinkomen hoofdkostwinner</b>
        <br>
        <form name="mijnForm3">
            <input type="radio" id="getal6" name="hoofdkostwinner"
                value="0" checked> Tot en met €1000,-
              <br>    
            <input type="radio" id="getal7" name="hoofdkostwinner"
                value="6"> €1001,- tot en met €2000,-
              <br>
            <input type="radio" id="getal8" name="hoofdkostwinner"
                value="18"> €2001,- tot en met €3000,-
             <br>
            <input type="radio" id="getal9" name="hoofdkostwinner"
                value="23"> €3001,- tot en met €4850
                  <br>
            <input type="radio" id="getal10" name="hoofdkostwinner"
                value="23"> €4850,- of hoger
            <br>
            <br>
            <b> Woonoppervlakte woning</b>
            <br>
        <form name="mijnForm4">
            <input type="radio" id="getal11" name="Oppervlakte"
                value="0" checked> tot en met60m²
              <br>    
            <input type="radio" id="getal12" name="Oppervlakte"
                value="0"> 60m² tot en met 80m²
              <br>
            <input type="radio" id="getal13" name="Oppervlakte"
                value="2">80m² tot en met 100m²
             <br>
            <input type="radio" id="getal14" name="Oppervlakte"
                value="6"> 100m² tot en met 120m²
                  <br>
            <input type="radio" id="getal15" name="Oppervlakte"
                value="8"> 120m² tot en met 150m²
                  <br>
            <input type="radio" id="getal16" name="Oppervlakte"
                value="20"> 150m² t/m 200m²
                  <br>
            <input type="radio" id="getal17" name="Oppervlakte"
                value="23"> 200 m² en meer
            <br>
        </form>
         <button onclick="checkTotal();">Bereken aantal punten</button>
         <center>
         Heel erg bedankt voor uw medewerking! 
         <br>
         Groetjes Warner Steinfort
        </center
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: How do you expect anyone to help you without seeing your program ???

Comment: Sorry, but this question is impossible to answer without you providing the code that is not working! Can you please edit the question and add the relevant code?

Comment: post some codes if you want help. It's hard to assume what's your problem

Comment: i've post the code now. I thought maybe its a common problem so you guys didn't need the code. But thanks if you would like to help!

Comment: That's a good start - now you have to describe what it is that doesn't work in IE. Any errors in the console? What it doesn't do that it should? Which version of IE?

Comment: "Doesn't work in IE" is a common problem, but there could be thousands of reasons. It's like saying "my Ford doesn't work" to a mechanic.

Comment: haha oke. I posted the wrong code. Now i've posted the right code.

Comment: Again -- any errors in the console? Which version of IE?

Comment: No error. Only when i push the button 'bereken aantal punten' I get now javascript alert with the awnser.. Internet explorer 8

Comment: Really, this question should have been "Why doesn't document.querySelectorAll('input:checked') work in IE8?" If you agree @warnerst please edit the title and the question _might_ get reopened.

Answer (score 1):

The argument to [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.querySelectorAll) works with valid CSS selectors. `:checked` is a [valid CSS3 selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#checked) but does not exist in CSS 2.1 which is what IE8 has implemented.

You can use jQuery to find the elements with `$('input:checked')` - see [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) which uses a polyfill for IE8 to provide cross-browser functionality.

Alternatively, without jQuery you could use a different approach to find which `<input>` elements are checked, for example you could find all the `<input>` elements and then loop through checking the `checked` property.

Answer (score 0):

FYI **document.querySelectorAll** is only supported in IE9 and IE10. If you are using IE6, and 7 this may not work. In IE8 this may not work if NOT using CSS2 selectors. Instead of using querySelectorAll use jQuery each. Just replace your code

```
var a =  document.querySelectorAll('input:checked'); 
  var total = 0;
  for(var x=0; x < a.length;x++){
  total += parseFloat( a[x].value );
}
```

**with this ONE**

```
 var total = 0;
   $("input:checked").each(function () {
     total += parseFloat($(this).val());
   });
```

Comment: The MSDN documentation for [`querySelectorAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/cc304115(v=vs.85).aspx) disagrees with you. It *is* supported in IE8 but only for the CSS 2 selectors.

Comment: For some perspective when it says not supported maybe refer to some components are not supported (by i.e. CSS2) but some are supported. The point here is not what is supported and what is not supported but what approach WORKS for all browsers.

Comment: No, you have stated `document.querySelectorAll is only supported in IE9 and IE10` which is incorrect. It **is** supported in IE8.